# Converting Jupyter to PDF using LaTeX

Tags: compiling

I am trying to convert a Jupyter notebook to PDF using LaTeX, but I am facing the issues below. I believe it has to do with graphs, that get generated when I compile my document. The file also contains references. Is there a way to fix this please?

```
Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater 
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 691.


! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in Machine_Learning_Project_2_f
iles/Machine_Learning_Project_2_36_1.png (no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.719 ...iles/Machine_Learning_Project_2_36_1.png}

? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

This is the code I am using to convert to PDF

```
ipython nbconvert Machine_Learning_Project_2.ipynb --to latex --template citation.tplx
latex Machine_Learning_Project_2.tex
bibtex Machine_Learning_Project_2.aux
pdflatex Machine_Learning_Project_2.tex
pdflatex Machine_Learning_Project_2.tex
pdflatex Machine_Learning_Project_2.tex
```

Comment: why are you using latex not pdflatex for the first run? (that is why you are getting an error as latex/dvips can not include png files)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks very much! That has worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your script is

```
latex Machine_Learning_Project_2.tex
```

latex/dvips can not include png files and explains the error that you show. Change that to `pdflatex`